Partial value font color in red using vba
I will see (1234.56) Dolar in Black when I run the following code
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Format(-1234.56, "#,##0.00;[Red](#,##0.00)") & " Dolar"

I would like to see (1234.56) in Red
and Dolar in Black.
Please note that characters and  characters count is variable.
I mean value could be 123.14 or 12.25 or 1.5 etc.
I mean Dolar could be Euro or Pound or Yen etc.
Update: The following code is very useful.
Sub Macro1()

'Following code makes "over" text as red color.

For i = 1 To 100
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value Like "*I love stackoverflow*" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Characters(InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value, "over", 1), 4).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next i

End Sub


You have to set the colors by character:
Sub formatSpecial()

Dim v As Double, vF As String
v = -1234.56
vF = format(v, "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)")


Dim c As Range
Set c = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
With c
    .Value = vF & " dolar"
    If v < 0 Then
        .Characters(1, Len(vF)).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
End With
End Sub


This function to will return the proper result even when ran multiple times over the same range.
Sub CurrencyFormatter(Target As Range, Optional CurrencyType As String = "Dolar")
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Value As String
    For Each Cell In Target
        If Len(Cell.Value) > 0 Then
            Value = Split(Cell.Value, " ")(0)
            Value = Format(Value, "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)")
            Cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
            Cell.Value = Value & " " & CurrencyType
            If Value < 0 Then
                Cell.Characters(1, Len(CStr(Value))).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Here I'm just having a little bit of fun exploiting Excel's paste feature.  Excel will pick up HTML formatting when you paste it into a worksheet.
Sub SpecialCurrencyFormatter(Target As Range, Optional CurrencyType As String = "Dolar")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const Template As String = "<html><span style ='color:@Color'>@Value</span> @CurrencyType</html>"
    Dim Clip As Object
    Set Clip = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim HTML As String
    Dim Value As Double
    For Each Cell In Target
        If Len(Cell.Value) > 0 Then
            Value = Split(Cell.Value)(0)
            HTML = Replace(Template, "@Color", IIf(Value < 0, "red", "black"))
            HTML = Replace(HTML, "@Value", Format(Value, "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)"))
            HTML = Replace(HTML, "@CurrencyType", CurrencyType)
            Clip.SetText HTML
            Clip.PutInClipBoard
            Cell.PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next
End Sub

